# Calling a function within a function [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

The instructions that I've been given tells me create 2 functions: first one (helloWorld) just has to print a basic string but the second one (helloWorldNTimes) has to call the first one 'n' amount of times. This is what I have so far - I either don't understand the question completely or misinterpreting it.

```
def helloWorld():
    print('Hello World')

def helloWorldNTimes(n):

def main():
    helloWorldNTimes(7)

main()
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: looks like you need to learn what loops are, specifically something called a [for loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)

Comment: So far so good! Now you just need to think of a looping structure to use in the `helloWorldNTimes` function..

Comment: I warmly suggest you to start with a good tutorial on the Python basics, e.g. the [one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) available on the Python official site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to study loops in programming language. Especially for loop.

You have to call function inside a loop. It can be either while or for loop. Then only it can be called n number of times.

Example :

```
def helloWorld():
    print ("Hello, World!")

for x in range(7):
    helloWorld()
```

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd function doesn't do anything... you have to call a loop "n" times to have it done:

```
def helloWorld():
    print('Hello World')

def helloWorldNTimes(n):
    for x in range(n):
        helloWorld()

def main():
    helloWorldNTimes(7)

main()
```